# .net Distinct() and complex conditons

Tags: c#, .net, duplicates, distinct

Assume I have a class

```
public class Audio
{
    public string artist   { get; set; }
    public string title    { get; set; }
    // etc.
}
```

Now I want to filter duplicates in list of such audio's by similarity (not EXACT match) condition. Basicaly it's Levenstein distance with treshold correction by string total length. The problem is, general tip about IEqualityComparer is "Always implement both GetHashCode and Compare". I obviuosly can't calc distance between strings in GetHashCode because it's not a compare method at all. However in this case even similar audio's will return different hashes and Distinct() will treat it as different objects and compare() method does not fired.

I tried to force GetHashCode always returns 0, so Compare called for each-to-each object in collection, but this is slow. So, finally, a question: is there anything I can do with .net out of the box or should I search some good algorithm for filtering?

Comment: I think you may be abusing `Distinct` here. For example, you may consider `ab` to be a duplicate of `bc` and `bc` to be a duplicate of `cd`, yet you would not consider `ab` to be a duplicate of `cd`. This makes `Distinct` not work for you.

Comment: Thanks, Gabe, I didn't thought about it. I see I should just read a good book about search algorithms.

Comment: If you have static, long list of objects - take a look at BK Trees, they can help you a lot in what you're trying to accomplish. I've written implementation in F# once, it's quite usable for your goal. You can store any object in it, compare it with levenshtein on any property by selector function. If you're interested, i can upload code to bitbucket.

Comment: I'm not familiar with F# but I think your code can show me right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest (first of all) not using **Distinct** or **GetHashCode**.

**GetHashCode** is too strict for your case (as @Gabe pointed out perfectly).
What you could do is:

1. Admit that you will have to compare an entire triangle (O(n^2) complexity) of instances pairs using the Levenshtein
2. Try to optimise that using every trick in the book: How does calculating the **Levenshtein distance from the empty string to the current one** sound (that is for each and every instance of Audio and probably for separately for both string properties) ?

That could end up (one might say) with a darn good **GetHashCode**.
But you can't use it like a **GetHashCode**, you should rather use it like so:

```
bool AreSimilar(Audio me, Audio you) {
  int cheapLevenshtein = Math.Abs(me.AbsoluteQuasiLevenshtein - you.AbsoluteQuasiLevenshtein);

  if (cheapLevenshtein < THRESHOLD) {

    int expensiveLevenshtein = Audio.LevenshteinBetween(me, you);
    var result = (expensiveLevenshtein < LIMIT);
    return result;

  } else
    return false;
}
```

And then you'd end up with a better or worse algorithm. This was just an idea and, of course: you can't use Distinct(). If you wish, you can write you very own extension method to make the whole thing look nice from a user programmer's perspective.

And yes the **AbsoluteQuasiLevenshtein** would be equal for things like: "ab" and "zy" but it would differ greatly between "ab" and "blahblahblahblah" and at least you would optimize things a bit. (The **GetHashCode** + **Distinct** approach posed an additional problem - the strictness of **GetHashCode**).

Comment: I get your point. I suppose easiest `AbsoluteQuasiLevenshtein` is a string length?

Comment: Indeed. And if not it's up to you to discover a better one (specifically for your case). And if you succeed please share :)

Answer (score 1):

Code for BKTree, with simple "c# interoperability" layer and example in c# is here:

https://bitbucket.org/ptasz3k/bktree

It's VS 2012 solution.

You start with building tree from all of your objects, passing selector function (x => x.Key.ToLowerInvariant() in example), then you search for a given key and levenshtein distance and tree returns all matching objects.

So, if i understand your problem correctly:

```
var bk = BKTree.CSharp.CreateBK(x => x.artist, audios);
var allArtists = audios.Select(x => x.artist);
var possibleDuplicates = allArtists.Select(x => new 
    { Key = x, Similiar = BKTree.CSharp.FindInBk(bk, x, treshold).ToList());
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just tried your library and figured out one thing: interop layer creates Generic `public static bktree<a, string, int> CreateBk<a>(Func<a, string> selector, IEnumerable<a> lines);` Am I right it's used strings as "keys"? If so, I can't used it for my puproses because similarity condition is more complex - it's calculated from Audio.artist, Audio.title and Audio.aid (string as well). Additionaly, I calculated string distance with correction by length (if string is long, treshold is higher), but this is optional step. Anyway, thanks for your code, I'll try to google around BK trees.

Comment: If you take a look at f# code you'll notice that you can parametrize bk tree with your own distance function 'key -> int (or any numeric type implementing comparison, to be more specific), where 'key can be 'object_stored. I didn't allow it thru c#, but it is very easy thing to do. There is one condition though, and it's specific for bk-trees. Your distance function must be metric. I think it'll be hard in your case to formally prove that your custom function is. Sorry that I couldn't help more. Good luck on your quest and give some info when you'll finish it!

Comment: One additional thought -> have you tried selector like (audio => audio.artist + audio.title + audio.aid) and tweaking levenshtein limit? It doesn't help for lenght threshold though. And second one - how will you decide which audio is duplicate of which? Manually?

Comment: Yes, I thought about concatenation and generally it should works, especially if user set up filtering by artist first. I'll use it if other solutions will be less elegant. Determination of "Master" copy among other duplicates is redundant in my case, I can just use any of it (first of it).

Comment: Well, I reach a final of this quest, and here some results: I failed in approach to modify F# code (I really newbie in F# and whole Functional Programming). Then I found BK Tree implementation on C#. Maybe I did something wrong, but this realisation created a tree with first audio from array as "parent" and all other audios to children of first audio. Any query against this tree runs eternally. Since I didn't study algorithm internal, I tried naive approach "enumerate array -> find doubles, remove it". It was kinda slow, but works. Then I added prefilter step, which removes obvious duplicates.

Comment: It gave me huge perfomance boost and I'm ok with filtering results. I have some other tricks to make filtering more relevant, but my problem generally solved. I'll not add another answer to topic because my research gone it's original way and answer can misdirect someone. Additionaly, final solution is close to **Eduard Dumitru** answer. **rkrahl** thanks for point me to BK Tree, I had fun with it :)